# Does Hartogs's Theorem for complex-analytic functions hold for real-analytic functions?

Tags: real-analysis, cv.complex-variables

Recall a very famous theorem due to Hartogs for complex analytic functions of several variables.

> **Hartogs's Theorem** Let $f$ be a  holomorphic function on a set $G \setminus K$, where $G$ is an open subset of $\mathbb{C}^n$ ($n \ge
>  2$) and $K$ is a compact subset of $G$. If the complement $G\setminus
>  K$ is connected, then $f$ can be extended to a unique to a unique
>   holomorphic function on $G$.

My question is does this theorem still hold if $f$ real-analytic?

By real-analytic, I mean that $f$ has a power series expansion on $G\setminus K$.

Comment: @SamHopkins  Thanks. It is related by I don't think it is a duplicate.

Comment: well, your question is better written than that question, at any rate.

Comment: @SamHopkins  Thanks.

Comment: @Boby, nevertheless, Ben McKay has answered you question there: consider $f(x_1,\dots,x_n)=e^{1/(x_1^2+\dots+x_n^2)}$.

Comment: @Kostya_I  But is this function real-analytic?

Comment: @Boby  This function is real-analytic.  The composition of real analytic functions is real analytic.  This is not trivial to prove, but is standard.